# how to get list values from jsp page to servlet in java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

```
 <c:forEach items="${scratchlistlotto }" var="sl">
      <tr class="fontstyle">
        <td  class="table_color1"><input  name="scratchid" type="hidden"  class="table_color1" id="scratchid" style="text-align:center" size="2" value="${sl.scratchid }" />
        <input name="binid" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="table_color1" id="binid" style="text-align:center" size="2" value="${sl.bin }" /></td>
        <td class="table_color1"><input readonly="readonly" name="upccode" type="text" class="table_color1" id="upccode" style="text-align:center" size="25" readonly="readonly" value="${sl.upccode }" /></td>
        <td class="table_color2"  ><input readonly="readonly" name="totalticketss" type="text" class="table_color22" id="totalticketss${sl.i }" style="text-align:right" size="6" value="${sl.totaltickets }"/></td>
        <td class="table_color2"  ><input readonly="readonly" name="openingbalance${sl.i }" type="text" class="table_color22" id="openingbalance${sl.i }"   size="6" value="${sl.closingbalance }" /></td>
        <td><input name="closingbalnce" type="text" class="text_border" onclick="Click(${sl.i })" id="closingbalnce" onchange="javascript:Total(this.value)"   style="text-align:right" size="6" /></td>
        <td class="table_color2"><input readonly="readonly" name="value" type="text" class="table_color22" id="value${sl.i }" style="text-align:right" size="6" value="${sl.values }" /></td>
        <td class="table_color2"  ><input readonly="readonly" name="ticketssold" type="text" class="table_color22" id="ticketssold${sl.i }" style="text-align:right" size="6" /></td>
        <td class="table_color2"  ><input readonly="readonly" name="total" type="text" class="table_color22" id="total${sl.i }" style="text-align:right" size="6" /> 
        </td>
        <td width="38" align="center"><input name="endoflife" type="checkbox" class="text_border" id="endoflife"    /></td>
        </tr></c:forEach>
```

> this is my list i want send this into servlet how can i do this please help me

Answer (score 0):

If the above block is inside a form tag & your form action is a servlet then everything(input tag elements) will be available to servlet as request parameters .

Comment: thank you for replay i know that  but we have multiple values in list and we need to send all values into servlet

Comment: Can explain me which list you are talking about .

Comment: ${scratchlistlotto } this is my array list so i have multiple values in my jsp page all values must send to servlet this is my need

Comment: scratchlistlotto must be in session scope as you are accessing it from  session scope in servlet. Please check whether scratchlistlotto is in session scope or not .